# Bound for covariance using the covariance properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

For $a \in \mathbb R^+$ and random variables $X$ and $Y$, are these two inequalities correct?

$$2\operatorname{cov}(X,aY) \leq \operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(aY) = \operatorname{var}(X)+a^2\operatorname{var}(Y) \tag{1}$$
$$2\operatorname{cov}(X,aY)=a \times 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) \leq a(\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)) \tag{2}$$
Since in my case $0<a<<1$ and $\operatorname{var}(X) \approx\operatorname{var}(Y)$, I guess (2) is clearly better (tighter). I just wanted confirmation, thanks.

Comment: If you care about tightness of the inequality, why are you giving up a factor of $1/2$? We have $$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \leqslant \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{Var}(X) + \mathrm{Var}(Y)\right).$$

Comment: thanks @snar, I forgot about the "2" in front of the covariance. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1=X-E(X)$ and $Y_1=Y-E(Y)$.
Then the inequality
$0 \le (X_1-Y_1)^2=X_1^2+Y_1^2-2X_1Y_1$ implies that
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=E(X_1 Y_1) \le \frac12  E(X_1^2+Y_1^2)=\frac12 \bigl(\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)\bigr)\,.$$
Both inequalities in the question follow, and can be improved by a factor of 2.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about the "2" in front of the covariance.